# free white spaces section in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I'm writing a document which will contain something like the image I included below. I don't want to use images because if I do, the document will contain a lot of images and I want to include this text in my LaTeX document the right way.

I don't know if this is possible, but can I have a section in latex, in which I can write whitespaces and tabs the way I do in a .txt document?

[image: content]

Comment: You can use a matrix. Can you paste this as text to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`verbatim` environment](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Verbatim_text):

```
\begin{verbatim}
The verbatim environment
  simply reproduces every
 character you input,
including all  s p a c e s!
\end{verbatim}
```

I'm not sure if tabs will do what you want; replace them by spaces if necessary.

Comment: yes, this is the way to _write whitespaces and tabs the way I do in a .txt document_.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `verbatim` environment is to use a tabular-like environment, here's a sketch:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{14}{c}}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &   &     &    \\
e & i & n & - & t & e & s & t & e & s & t  &   &     &    \\
t & e & s & t &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &   & I=0 & j=0\\
  & t & e & s & t &   &   &   &   &   &    &   & I=1 & j=0\\
  &   & t & e & s & t &   &   &   &   &    &   & I=2 & j=0\\
  &   &   & t & e & s & t &   &   &   &    &   & I=3 & j=0\\
  &   &   &   & t & e & s & t &   &   &    &   & I=4 & j=1\\
  &   &   &   &   & t & e & s & t &   &    &   & I=5 & j=2\\
  &   &   &   &   &   & t & e & s & t &    &   & I=6 & j=3\\
  &   &   &   &   &   &   & t & e & s & t  &   & I=7 & j=4\\
\multicolumn{14}{l}{Und dann wird j auf 1...             }\\
  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & t & e & s  & t & I=8 & j=2\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and its output.

[image: tabular]

In my opinion a `tabular` (or other table environment) here has the advantage that you can then configure spacing, font family and size, etc.